# Guidance for Client side

Tags: design-patterns, server, scalability, client-server, iot

We have created software for Rugged and mobile devices, and it gets deployed on the device. Admin has a provision to send an update to those devices.

We use GCM or WNS for sending a notification to the devices that it has an update.

**Problem:**

If all the devices request for an update at the same time, then we will have a load burst in the server.

**Design**

**Current**
Now we buffer the request in the server 100 per hour and send it to the mobile devices. The update process takes long hours to finish.

**My design**
Instead, I want to send the update to every device with a time-based throttling to the client. I will group 200 to 300 device per minute to ask for an update.

I am looking for Guidance to see if there is a better option also feedback on the current option.

Comment: How long does each update take? How slow can you stand to make your server?

Comment: It takes 5 to 30 seconds.

Comment: What bottleneck do you hit? network capacity or CPU/memory?

Comment: Network Capacity as the other services needs to running

Comment: I don't know why a negative point is given for the question.

Comment: You mentioned in a comment on an answer that you have a cloud and on-premise option. What does that mean? I thought you were pushing software out to mobile devices.

Comment: So the updates may not be coming from your servers directly? Whose network/server capacity are you attempting to manage? The on-premise solution could authorise and defer the actual update to your own distribution, perhaps the company could proxy the version package or use a multi-cast. If you control the package down-loader on the devices why not use a controlled bit-torrent?

Answer (score 1):

If your constraint is truly just the server capacity - then you might consider cloud infrastructure options. This would shift the scaling concerns in your architecture to the cloud and allow you to rely on the elasticity of the cloud providers:

### Examples

AWS lambdas to send your updates. A good example on using AWS as the backend for mobile development can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-custom-android.html

AZURE Functions to send your updates.  This example is probably not as directly relevant to you, but gives you a sense of the capability: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-mobile-apps  Also, since you tagged IOT, Azure has an IOT HUB that can do a lot, including updating device firmware: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-firmware-update

Ewan brought up Content Delivery Networks(CDN) as an option (see comment below) - and that's a good choice as well. AWS has [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/%20%22AWS%20Cloudfront), Google and Microsoft also have CDN options.

Finally - if incorporating third party Mobile Device Management (MDM) solutions is an option - then consider automating something like AirWatch, Intune or Zoho MDM solutions (I recommend focusing on cloud versions that leverage the elasticity of the cloud). This would give the MDM the update challenge - and they have spent years in this space.
[architecture](/questions/tagged/architecture)

Comment: surely functions and lambdas are not good choices compared to s3 or a CDN?

Comment: Agree on CDN - and I will modify my answer (I should have thought of that upfront). In terms of functions/lambdas not being a good option - depends on the architecture and complexity, so the range of options from lambda to CDN to MDM solution covers a broad spectrum of design choices - I think

Comment: @daDa Problem is we have cloud and On-prem option for the product.  That's the reason I am thinking of making the client get the schedule to get an update?